# Number of elements in cyclic group that satisfy an exponent

Tags: rsa, modular-arithmetic, finite-field, prime-numbers

I'm having trouble with solving the following question:

> Given two distinct prime numbers $p, q$ where $(p-1)$ and $(q-1)$ are not divisible by $3$, define $n=pq$.
>
> For how many elements in $\mathbb Z^*_n$ $\exists b$ for which: $b^3\equiv a\ (mod\ n)$

Given the fact that $|\mathbb Z^*_n| = \phi(n)=(p-1)(q-1)$, I could conclude that the number of elements are dependent on $p$ and $q$.

But I'm not sure how to tie together that fact with that $(p-1)$ and $(q-1)$ are not divisible by 3.

I tried to use Fermat's Little Theorem, but since $n=pq$ is not a prime number, it didn't seem to help, as well as the Chinese Remainder Theorem, but to no success.

I would appreciate any insight on the matter.

Thank you!

Comment: Consider the case that  $(−1)$ and $(−1)$ are divisible by 3? What do you see?

Comment: In this case, if we restate $b^3 \equiv a\ (mod\ p)$ and $b^3 \equiv a\ (mod\ q)$ due to the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

We can let $x \equiv b^{(p-1)/3}$ and $y \equiv b^{(q-1)/3}$, the exponents are integers by our assumption, and we could claim that there are exactly 3 solutions for $b$ in the range $[0, p-1]$ and $[0, q-1]$.

By the Chinese Remainder Theorem there would be exactly 9 solutions for $b$ in the range $[0, pq-1]$.

But that doesn't help me find what is the case where they AREN'T divisible by 3.

Comment: Hint: when $p-1$ is not divisible by $3$, show that there are positive integers $d_p$ such that $3\,d_p\equiv1\pmod{p-1}$. Try to raise to such power $d_p$ both sides of the equation $b^3\equiv a\pmod p$ (that was rightly obtained thru the CRT), and use Fermat's little theorem. For (virtual) bonus points: more generally, for how many integers $a$ in $[0,n)$ does there exist $b$ for which $b^3\equiv a\pmod n$ ? You are welcome to write an answer to your own question.

Comment: BTW: terminology nit: the group $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$ (where $n$ has two distinct odd factors) is not cyclic; there is no single element that generates the entire group.

Comment: katz/lindel's proof of #QR_n in chapter 13.4.1 (second ed.) should help

Comment: @fgrieu, putting that in perspective, how can there be a positive integer $d_p$ such that $3 d_p \equiv 1\pmod{p-1}$? Wouldn't that mean that $3 d_p \equiv 0\pmod{p}$, even though $p$ is prime?

Comment: $3\,d_p\equiv1\pmod{p-1}$ is to be understood† as $3\,d_p\equiv1\pmod{(p-1)}$, meaning by definition that $3\,d_p-1$ is a multiple of $p-1$. And it's quite possible. e.g. with $p=17$, $d_p=11$ will do, because $3\times11\equiv1\pmod{16}$. († note: $\bmod$ with an opening parenthesis immediately on it's left [as typset with `\pmod` in LaTex] is not an operator; it's a qualifier of the congruence on it's left. Reading $3\,d_p\equiv1\pmod{p-1}$ gives "3 [times] d p is congruent to 1 [pause] modulo p minus 1" )

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, @fgrieu. I'm really trying to connect the dots here, but simply can't arrive to the number of elements $b$ which satisfy the equivalence. I can assume that there are positive integers $d_p$ which satisfy $3\,d_p\equiv1\pmod{p-1}$, (And do the same for $q$). So for $b^{3d_p}\equiv a^{d_p}\pmod p$, we can state that $d_p = 1 + k*(p-1)$ for some $k$, then using Fermat's Little Theorem we could play around with the exponent, but how do I tie it in with the amount of elements which satisfy the original question?

Comment: "play around with the exponent" will give you a necessary condition for $b\bmod p$ that must hold if $b^3\equiv a\pmod n$. Same for $b\bmod q$. Use the CRT to make that a necessary condition for $b\bmod n$. Then show that this condition is sufficient to imply $b^3\equiv a\pmod n$. At this point you have exhibited a $b$ for each $a\in\mathbb Z^*_n$ and can conclude. For (virtual) bonus points, do that for $a\in[0,n)$ instead of $a\in\mathbb Z^*_n$.